# why does it make intuitive sense to integrate the density of an object to get its mass?

Tags: integration

I am trying to wrap my head around this but i don't quite understand, my understanding is that the object is cut so small such that the density at each place is the same. where does the volume come in play here?

Comment: [Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) "or *volumetric mass density*, of a substance is its mass per unit volume." To get the *mass* we have to "add" together all the "units" of volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the small pieces have a little mass $$\Delta m=\rho \Delta V= \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z$$

Comment: the fact that we are integrating across a 3 dimensional objection is what does not make sense to me. in this case wouldn't you need to integrate it across x, y and z(use triple integration)?

Comment: Density can also be defined as mass per unit area or unit length depending upon the specific problem to solve. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: yeah, i get it now. dV does not necessarily always mean that all the dimensions are changing, just a change in one of the dimensions alters the volume, thus you us single, double and triple integration according to how many dimensions are changing in the volume. if some of the dimensions of the volume are not changing they are presumed to be constants

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{density}=\text{mass}/\text{volume}$$

$$\int \text{density}dV \approx \sum \text{density} \times \text{volume}$$

Comment: since you are integrating it in terms of v, shouldn't you use triple integration?

Comment: @studiousstudent Here by $\int$ I mean $\iiint$